# How to make footnote into tooltips in Blogdown?

Tags: r-markdown, markdown, bookdown, blogdown

I'm using Rmarkdown to make a **blogdown post**, and I'm hoping to implement something I saw in Hadley Wickham's *Advanced R* online [book](https://adv-r.hadley.nz/index.html), which is a footnote link that when clicked on opens as a tooltip instead of in the footer of the page. See image below for an example.

[image]

I have no idea how he did this and I couldn't find any options in the source code that reference footnotes or tooltips. In the [source](https://github.com/hadley/adv-r/blob/dc49c3872c3530ac08716fd4f4c235b01266a4ce/Functions.Rmd#L337-L339) for this page, the footnote is just a regular footnote (no special packages appear to be used). Thank you for your help!